# Make echo ignore spaces?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I have a file called temp1

```
   sCellEventTrap-03-27 TRAP-TYPE  -- CAC Code: 01
        ENTERPRISE compaq
        VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,
                     scellSWComponent,
                     scellECode,
                     scellCAC,
                     scellEIP}
        DESCRIPTION
             "Severity: Critical -- failure or failure imminent. A physical disk drive has experienced an ID block inconsistency."
           --#TYPE      "StorageCell Event"
           --#SUMMARY   "SCellName-TimeDate %s : SWCID %d : ECode: %d : CAC %d : EIP %d."
           --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,}
           --#SEVERITY  CRITICAL
           --#TIMEINDEX 136
           --#STATE     WARNING
        ::= 13600807
```

Applying this on temp1

> prvar=$(awk '/VARIABLES/,/DESCRIPTION/ {gsub("VARIABLES"," "); gsub("DESCRIPTION"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print;print ":%s"}' temp1)

Gives me   (what I want)

```
echo $prvar

scellNameDateTime :%s scellSWComponent :%s scellECode :%s scellCAC :%s scellEIP :%s :%s
```

However this (the format not wanted)

```
echo "$prvar" 

             scellNameDateTime 
:%s
                     scellSWComponent 
:%s
                     scellECode 
:%s
                     scellCAC 
:%s
                     scellEIP 
:%s

:%s
```

I am to use `prvar` in `echo` along with text like this

> echo  "blah blah blah $prvar"

Doing this what I get

```
blah blah blah              scellNameDateTime 
:%s
                     scellSWComponent 
:%s
                     scellECode 
:%s
                     scellCAC 
:%s
                     scellEIP 
:%s

:%s
```

**What I want it to print**

```
blah blah blah scellNameDateTime :%s scellSWComponent :%s scellECode :%s scellCAC :%s scellEIP :%s :%s
```

The `""` on the prvar when using `echo` create the problem. What can I do so that prvar is printed in a just above format?

**EDIT**
Well turns out it doesnt make a difference whatever I type in my SCRIPT `echo "$prvar"` and `echo $prvar` print the same thing --- the format i don't want. The Terminal and the script are behaving differently. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion and an extended glob to "normalize" the whitespace.

```
# enable extended globs so that +([[:space:]]) matches one or more whitespace
shopt -s extglob

# replace all occurances of one or more whitespace with a single space
prvar=${prvar//+([[:space:]])/ }

echo "blah blah blah $prvar blah blah"
```

This allows you to safely quote the variable. If you don't quote the variable, word splitting is not the only thing that will happen. The shell will also attempt to replace words with filenames, if they contain glob characters like `*`, `?`, `[...]`.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to quote (") everything in echo. You can have many strings. Simply dont quote prvar:

```
echo "blah blah blah" $prvar
```

In the shell (which is expanding $prvar for you before echo even sees it), spaces inside quotes (") are preserved, but spaces and tabs outside quotes are reduced to one space. eg

```
echo "a        b"        d            e
a        b d e
```

Comment: What if it were like this `"blah blah blah $prvar blah blah blah"` ? then what  can I do ?

Comment: @SamFlynn: `echo "blah blah blah" $prvar "blah blah blah" `

Comment: Well turns out it doesnt make a difference whatever i type in my script `echo "$prvar"` and `echo $prvar` print the same thing --- the format i don't want.  The Terminal and the script are behaving differently any work around for this?